# Custom font with dmenu

Tags: fonts

I found references at various places running dmenu like so :

```
dmenu_run -b -fn 'Inconsolata 12'
```

However, whatever variation of the font name I try, I always get `dmenu: warning: cannot load font <font name>`

`fc-list | grep cons` gives me:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf: Inconsolata:style=Medium
```

It does not show in `xlsfonts` and all the fonts that do show up with xlsfonts work fine.

What is the correct way to reference these fonts from command line ?

Also, is that a standard way to reference fonts or will it change when using programs like `pango`?

Comment: Lol... dmenu only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard version of dmenu doesn't include support for xft fonts. To use fonts like Inconsolata you'll need to build a patched version of dmenu.

1. Download the [source code](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/) and the [patch](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/xft).
2. Open up a terminal, `cd` to the directory containing both the source code and the patch.
3. Run the following commands to apply the patch:

   ```
   tar zxvf dmenu-4.5.tar.gz
   cd dmenu-4.5
   mv ../dmenu-4.5-xft.diff .
   patch -p1 < dmenu-4.5-xft.diff
   ```
4. To build the modified version of dmenu, you'll need to have the following packages installed: `libxft-dev libxft2 libxinerama-dev`
5. UPDATE on UBUNTU 14.04 the build fails with

   > fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory

   to fix this edit the config.mk File and change

   > XFTINC = -I/usr/local/include/freetype2

   to

   > XFTINC = -I/usr/include/freetype2
6. Run the following commands to build and install the modified version of dmenu:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Isn't sucklesstools included with i3 ?

Comment: Clone from `http://git.suckless.org/dmenu` and apply patch from `http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/xft` on master then `make`.  `chmod +x dmenu_path` and install (or just add symlinks to dmenu, dmenu_run, dmenu_path, and stest).

Answer (score 3):

You must to use the [X Logical Font Description (XLFD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description) full name for the font provided by `xfontsel`. For example, you can use something like this : `-bitstream-*-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`:

```
dmenu_run -b -fn -bitstream-*-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

`xfontsell` tool allows you to preview the different settings.

If you want to use a syntax like:

```
dmenu_run -b -fn <family>-<size>:<name>=<value>
```

which is closer to what you asked, you can use [Xft support](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/xft) patch. See [here](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/) the instructions about how to use a patch for `dmenu`.

Answer (score 2):

Since dmenu 4.6 (released in Nov 2015), XFT font rendering is enabled by default ([4.6 Release Notes](http://lists.suckless.org/dev/1511/27503.html))
 and this just works:

```
dmenu_run -fn 'Inconsolata 12'
```